# How to use Angular factory to persist data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which allow users to fill in some data bind to a ng-model called "person" in my controller, the person model also stores image data. I want to build an factory, so when users left the page it I can call this method to persist the existing form data and image data, when they come back to the page, I can fetch them from the factory, after form submitted, I will call the factory reset method to clear it.

I have something but doesn't work, so when I am leaving the page I call storeData(), when I am back I call get(), It seems like when after submission, the resetPersonService() doesn't really clear the stored data, any idea?

```
.factory("PersonService", [function(){
            var newPerson = {};
            function storeData(person){
                if (person.image_data){
                    newPerson.image_data = person.image_data;
                }
                if (person.description)
                    newPerson.description = person.description;
                return newPerson;
            };

            function resetPersonService(){
                newPerson = {}; 
            };

            function get(){
                if (Object.keys(newPerson).length == 0){
                    return {};
                } else {
                    return newPerson;
                }
            };
            return {
                store: function(person){
                    return storeData(person);       
                },
                reset: function(){
                    resetPersonService();
                },
                get: function(){
                    return get();       
                }
            }
        }])
```

Comment: I am thinking, Why you are not using localStorage for this.?

Comment: What do you mean "person comes back to the page"? As in after a full page reload? Can you post the controller code as well?

Comment: I am not worried about page reload, because it an mobile app. So I mean when user nav back to the form page, I think Ved maybe right, localstorage could be more straightforward.